# On finding the index of the first >= element

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Given an *ordered* list `A` of integers, and an integer `q <= A[-1]`, I want to find the smallest non-negative index `i` such that `A[i] >= q`.

I can think of ways to do this *efficiently* (e.g. with some form of binary search), but I'd like to know if there's anything in either Python's standard library or in numpy/scipy that I can use to implement this.

(For example, something analogous to MATLAB's `interp1` function.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python provides a module for performing binary search operations on a sorted list: [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html).  I believe the function you want is `bisect_left`.

Comment: The equivalent numpy function is [`searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html).